# deploying geoserver on linux or windows: performance implications?

Tags: geoserver, performance, hosting

I am deploying my first geoserver in production. I develop on a Macbook Pro retina, and my client uses Windows, so I deploy on Windows servers.

My first impression was that geoserver seemed a lot slower on the Windows server than my development machine, but I was able to improve this greatly using all the performance tips found all over the net. In short: install Native JAI, tune jvm, enable gwc. But still.

In my search for performance tips, I stumbled accross the following results: http://www.slideshare.net/gatewaygeomatics.com/wms-performance-shootout-2011

In this slideshow is shown that MapServer on linux is considerably faster than Mapserver on windows. I tried to look for a similar results or benchmark for Geoserver, but did not find it.

Aside of that I also wonder if the container has any impact on the performance of GeoServer (e.g. jetty/tomcat/jboss/...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux is more customizable and with the tweaks users can see better performance.

[This link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150906001033/http://boundlessgeo.com/whitepaper/geoserver-production-2/) explains 3 factors to make linux a better solution for geoserver

> The quality of a GeoServer deployment in a production environment is
>   measured by three criteria:
>
> - **Reliability**: the server’s ability to successfully fulfill requests for maps and data.
> - **Availability**: the overall uptime of the server (including both planned and unplanned outages).
> - **Performance**: how quickly the server can fulfill client requests

Comment: Thanks, I had already read that document, and applied some of the great advice to tune the performance of my windows servers. But in the document I do not find anything directly related to arguments preferring to choose linux over windows servers. I would rather prefer some hard data :)

Comment: Here is GIS Knowledge and 'experience' of GIS-SE  users http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1513/geoserver-what-are-the-pros-cons-of-running-on-a-windows-server-vs-a-linu

Comment: Yes, I had found that already too, but it says nothing about performance, nor hard figures. If it was my choice, I would go for an ubuntu system. But to convince my client, I need a little more than a personal preference.

Comment: I don't know of any hard data on linux vs. windows. But you can tell your client that the developers of GeoServer primarily test on linux servers. At least 95% of the 100 or so real production instances I know run GeoServer on Linux. Windows is supported, but the developers consider it a good way to get people to try it out easily, and expect most production instances are running Linux. So I'd go with Linux just because there's more project history on Linux, so it's just more likely to work right at all times. And ubuntu is a great choice.